# Change label on click with Tkinter Python

Tags: python

I wrote a python code that changes the label text after every click. Now I have to write a test to confirm new text is indeed displaying after each click. I looked around online and couldn't find a way to do. Really new with python and programming and know there are easier ways to do some codes but for now I don't have that knowledge.

```
import Tkinter as tk

li="This Text Will Keep Changing Every Time You Click!".split()

def toggle_text():
    """Change text after each click """

    if lbl["text"] == "Hi!":
            lbl["text"] = li[0]    
    elif lbl["text"] == li[0]:
            lbl["text"] = li[1]   
    elif lbl["text"] == li[1]:
            lbl["text"] = li[2]   
    elif lbl["text"] == li[2]:
            lbl["text"] = li[3]    
    elif lbl["text"] == li[3]:
            lbl["text"] = li[4]   
    elif lbl["text"] == li[4]:
            lbl["text"] = li[5]   
    elif lbl["text"] == li[5]:
            lbl["text"] = li[6]   
    elif lbl["text"] == li[6]:
            lbl["text"] = li[7]
    elif lbl["text"] == li[7]:
            lbl["text"] = li[8]       
    else:
       lbl["text"] = "Hi!"

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Click the Button")
button = tk.Button( text="Click", width=12, command=toggle_text)
button.pack(padx=100, pady=10)
lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Hi!")
lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The code is not the best but it does work. I tried to use a for loop but the text didn't change so I just found a workaround. Now how do I test that a new text is displayed after each click?

Answer (score 0):

For better dealing with Tkinter I recommend you set your GUI within a class:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class DynamicLabel:

    TEXT_LIST="This Text Will Keep Changing Every Time You Click!".split() + ["Hi"]

    def __init__(self, toplvl):

        self.index = 0
        self.new_text = "Hi"
        self.old_text = "Hi"

        self.button = tk.Button(toplvl, text="Click", width=12, command=self.toggle_text)
        self.button.pack(padx=100, pady=10)

        self.label = tk.Label(toplvl, text="Hi")
        self.label.pack()

    def toggle_text(self):
        self.old_text = self.label['text']
        self.new_text = self.TEXT_LIST[self.index%len(self.TEXT_LIST)]
        self.label['text'] = self.new_text
        self.index += 1
        print "Text Changed: %r" % self.check_text()

    #This one may check if the text changed, returning True or False
    def check_text(self):
        return self.old_text != self.new_text

root = tk.Tk()
DynamicLabel(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And the verification should be streamed to the terminal when the button is clicked.